# Php uploads only the last file in $_files array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that handles server side upload of files pushed to it via an ajax script; the ajax script actually does the loop through the file input and pushes the file to the server: a print_r($_FILES); an array of files, but only one file ends up being uploaded to server. this is my PHP script for the file upload;

```
$i=0;

foreach($_FILES as $file_item){
    $i++;
    //print_r($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);

    echo  $file_item['tmp_name'][$i];

    $sourcePath = $file_item['tmp_name'][$i];
    $targetPath = "uploads/".basename($file_item['name'][$i]); //. round(microtime(true)) . '.' . $file_item['tmp_name'][$i];
    echo $targetPath;
    move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath);

}
```

and this is my ajax script for front-end;

```
$(function(){
    $('#file').change(function(){
    for (i=0; i < this.files.length; i++){
        console.log(this,'this');
        console.log(this.files[i]);
        var file=this.files[i];     
        var imagetype=file.type;
        var imgtags =['image/jpeg','image/pjpeg',"image/png","image/jpg","image/gif"];      
        if(imgtags.indexOf(imagetype)>0){
            Materialize.toast('File Is an image!', 2000);           
            var filereader=new FileReader();
            filereader.onload=FileLoadCheck;
            filereader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
            FileUploadAjaxCall();
        }
            }
    });
    function FileLoadCheck(e){
        console.log(e,'Object');
        $('#previewImage').attr('src',e.target.result);
    }

});

function FileUploadAjaxCall(){  
    $.ajax({
        url:'fileupload.php?_'+new Date().getTime(),
            type:'POST',
            data:new FormData($('#UploadMedia').get(0)),
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data,'data');
                Materialize.toast('File Upload Successfully!', 2000);
            }
    });
}
```

this is the html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadMedia">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">               
            <div class="col s6 push-s3">
                <div class="card card-panel hoverable">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="images/images.png" class="img-responsive" id="previewImage">
                        <span class="card-title">Image Show Here</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="file-field input-field">
                            <div class="btn" style="background-color:#757575">
                                <span>File</span>
                                <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
                            </div>
                            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>                                                      
                </div>
            </div>                              
        </div>              
    </div>  
</form>
```

> i have checked similar questions and php.ini max_upload limit already without luck

Comment: If you cannot find a solution for this then why not cue the uploads client-side and have them upload one by one? Simply check the ajax response to call the ajax request again to upload the next (in line) file.... This way, if an error does occur it isn't going to stop the other files from uploading giving the client chance to try re-upload that one file rather than all of them...

Comment: isn't it more efficient to just push the entire array to the PHP script for uploads and leave the browser to handle another task? and how would that be implemented?

Comment: By iterating through the `files[]` just like you do to display a preview or whatever you are using the `FileReader()` for.

Comment: what is the html for this? You are looping over `this.files` and calling the upload method for each iteration but in the `FileUploadAjaxCall` you pass always the same data from `#UploadMedia`. Basicly you create N ajax calls with the same data for each call. Not sure how `print_r($_FILES)` prints more than 1 file.

Comment: i have edited to include the html

Comment: ok, I have seen the angle you coming from, thanks but how exactly do I pass the current file to the `FileUploadAjaxCall`function for $_POST..ing @insider